# Why Google map Api key need to change frequently

Tags: android, google-maps

I am facing an issue that I have created api key for google maps with debug and release key SHA like this :

[image]

And updated that key in my manifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBY34afkPU6TRw5v9yM1wqI3vFbk90zMt0" />
```

with all required permissions but after every few days google map looks blanks Like this :

[image]

After changing key in my manifest map is visible.
My question is why I need to change this API key after every few days?

Comment: where you check ?emulator or real device?

Comment: First of all tell me why you need to changed API key every few days?

Comment: real device with wifi and gps on

Comment: @MD it shows blank map as shown in picture

Comment: So for that you changed key every day!!! Just check your key properly..

Comment: @MD not every day I have mentioned after few days

Comment: It's not require to changed it every few days.....

Comment: You should not ever need to change it.  Do you have it set up with both your debug sha1 and your keystore sha1 for signed apks?

Comment: @DanielNugent yes my concern is that only.
Yes I have setup both debug SHA1 and release SHA1

Comment: I dont understand why this questions got `11 up vote`. It's does not make sense to me. It's already contain answer just OP want to check API key proerply.

Answer (score 5):

If you use debug key and publish app, it will be blank. when checking export-> application-> map will be blank because you use debug keystore. To use production key, follow this step.

While signing app,ie in production, you want to use release key. For that you want to compare that with signed apk

Step 1:

Say for example your apk name is A and you are signing and creating a keystore for A.apk ie A.keystore will be created in some drive location.Let's consider it in E drive.

step 2:

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 finger print

copy and paste that in google map console, it wll generate a key.use it in maps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change because you might change development system or developer key.

default.keystore will change on format system or change the system.

To solve this issue.

Make keystore and every time sign with the keystore and install in device.

So you will not get to change API key frequently.